# Android NDK won't build library because Bitmap.h is missing?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm using the Android NDK to build a library. I had everything working well, but then I needed to change a package name which is referenced in the library. I tried to build the library again once I made the change, by calling ndk-build in its folder, but this is the only output I get and it does not seem to be fully building:

```
C:\my-app\jni>ndk-build -B
"Compile++ thumb : filters <= filters.cpp
C:/a-fa-outsidelands//jni/filters.cpp:4:28: fatal error: android/bitmap.h: No such file     or directory
compilation terminated.
```

This then leads to an unsatisfied link error when I try to run the application. I'll post my .mk file, but I don't think that should matter because my previous library was working with this .mk file. I'm doing the rebuild (the -B parameter) because it is over a previous build. Any suggestions? Here's my .mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := filters
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := filters.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -lm -llog -ljnigraphics

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

What's the `android:targetSdkVersion` in the app's manifest? IIRC, `bitmap.h` was not introduced until SDK v8.

EDIT: Was the last successful build on the same machine, with the same NDK version? Does the #include line use `<android/bitmap.h>` as opposed to `"android/bitmap.h"`?

EDIT2: Did the targetSdkVersion change since the last build? I found a funny thing: there's no `android-10` under `android-ndk-xx\platforms`. Try creating a blank `android-10` folder under `android-ndk-xx\platforms` and copying the contents of `android-9` there. I'm honestly not sure what else to check.

Comment: The target is 10, the minimum is 8

Comment: It was the same NDK version, and where exactly do I look to find out what the #include line uses?

Comment: filters.cpp, line 4. Same NDK version - but was it the same machine?

Comment: It uses <android/bitmap.h>
And no, I am not currently on the same machine, but I got this exact error on the original machine too.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. Then I found this answer.
[Android bitmap.h is not found for native code compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661708/android-bitmap-h-is-not-found-for-native-code-compile)

Just ran:

```
ndk-build APP_PLATFORM=android-8
```