# Android bitmap.h is not found for native code compile

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to compile code using the Android NDK. I have previously used this code fine, but changed one thing in it and now it will not compile. The error that shows up is:

```
"Compile++ thumb : filters <= filters.cpp
C:/Android/my-app//jni/filters.cpp:4:28: fatal error: android
/bitmap.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [C:/Android/my-app//obj/local/armeabi/objs/filters/
filters.o] Error 1
```

My bitmap.h file is defined in the library as:

```
#include <android/bitmap.h>
```

I know that bitmap.h is only there after a target-skd build of 8 or higher, and mine is a target of 10 and min of 8. Any suggestions? This is driving me crazy and used to work!Thanks for any help you can provide.

Edit: Here is my Android.mk file also

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := filters
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := filters.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -lm -llog -ljnigraphics

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android NDK won't build library because Bitmap.h is missing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656833/android-ndk-wont-build-library-because-bitmap-h-is-missing)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Got it to work. I was using SDK tools revision 20, and platform-tools revision 12. In order to get it to compile, I had to specify the APP_PLATFORM in the command line (apparently these revisions default to something else).

Just ran:

```
ndk-build APP_PLATFORM=android-8
```

and it built!

Answer (score 1):

Insert APP_PLATFORM=android-8 into file Application.mk

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer bellow helped me also.
I tried setting the APP_PLATFORM variabile to android-10 from Application.mk (as I expected this option should also be where the APP_ABI is), but that didn't help.
Pretty non-intuitive, but whatever works, right..?